# Under what circumstances does NSURLSession return nil for its data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http

I have crash reports that are caused by not performing a nil-check on data within a dataTask completion-block. Fixing the error is trivial, however, under what circumstances does this even happen? In ALL of my tests, I always receive an NSData with 0 bytes, not nil--but obviously it's happening if it's in the crash logs. I've tried disabling the connection (via airplane mode), feeding back invalid HTTP responses, timing out the HTTP response, minimizing the app while the connection is still transferring, etc, etc... I've done everything I can think of, but never get data to be nil--just 0 bytes. What am I not thinking of?

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // What kind of server-response/connection-scenarios would make data be nil...? (not 0 bytes)
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: What does the error say? `if( !data ){ NSLog(@"%@", error); }`

Comment: That's the thing: I'm trying to find the scenario that produces nil data--so I don't know/have the NSError. Only production users were encountering it, and all I'd get back was a stacktrace. ("Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException data parameter is nil")

Comment: Are you aware of [iOS 9's ATS disabling of HTTP in favor of HTTPS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html)? Could iOS version be a factor?

Comment: That's a good thought--especially since all of the reports are coming from iOS9. I'll point it to an http server that doesn't support https and see if I can get a nil response back! Thanks for the idea. I'll report back in a few.

Comment: @JoshCaswell : **Yes!** You, sir, rock. That's exactly the scenario. Thank you much. If you put this as an answer (instead of a comment) to this question, I'll accept it.

Comment: My comment is not much more than a suggestion; it would be better if you'd [post your own answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow) explaining what exactly is wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Glad I could help, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've come up with an answer, with the suggestions from Josh Caswell.

It appears that it is **only iOS9** that NSURLSession will be nil; previous versions just contain a zero byte NSData. I've gotten a nil data response when an http request fails to upgrade to https (see the above comments for context), but also any time the app can't make a connection--this includes being on a phone call with some carriers/phones, or poor service. This leads me to believe it wasn't an ATS-specific case, but instead, any error involving the data-transport-layer seems to cause data to be nil.

**So, in short, the important thing to know is that data only starts being nil as of iOS9.**

Comment: This helped me out tremendously! The 'nil' response was causing my NSURLSession to crash upon returning from sleep mode (unlock). by calling return after checking 'nil' and creating a new session I was able to fix it √ nice work

Comment: Yeah. I had an issue with iOS 8 and less devices because of this. Funny because the document clearly states the data will be `nil` if the request fails.